# How can rhodobacter possess a single 'PS-II' like reaction center?

Tags: plant-physiology, photosynthesis

I recently came across an information in my book [Trueman's Elementary Biology](http://www.truemanbooks.com/details.php?prod_id=43&title=) ,  a popular text in India, that photosynthetic bacteria like *Rhodobacter*, *Rhodopseudomonas* etc. possess a single photosystem where the reaction center is PS-II like. Now how can PS-II work as a single unit? As far as I know, PS-I can operate singly in cyclic mode generating ATP only. But PS-II works in conjunction with PS-I to generate ATP, $\ce{O2} $ and $\ce{NADPH} + \ce{H^+} $. So how can PS-II work as a single unit in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[McEwan (1994) *Photosynthetic electron transport and anaerobic metabolism in purple non-sulfur phototrophic bacteria.* Antonie Van Leeuwenhoek 66: 151-164.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7747929)

...The **purple non-sulfur** bacteria ... carry out **photosynthesis** under **anaerobic** conditions. Photosynthetic electron transport is **cyclic** and involves ... **two redox complexes** ... **reaction center** (RC) [and] **cytochrome bc1 complex**. ... This cycle of electron transfer, [mediated
by **ubiquinone** (UQ) and a **c-type cytochrome**,] is linked to the generation of a **proton motive force** ... across the cytoplasmic membrane.

[image: Pathways of cyclic photosynthetic electron transfer in *Rhodobacter capsulatus*. Source: Figure 1 in McEwan, 1994]

Comment: That means, the PS II in case of Rhodopseudomonas is a bit different from that found in a typical chloroplast.

Answer (score 0):

TL,DR: I think you've just swapped PS-I and PS-II.

Recall the differences between PS-I and PS-II.  **Bear in mind that PS-I and PS-II were not so named because of the order they run in, but rather because of the order in which they were discovered.  PS-II comes before PS-I chronologically.**

PS-II basically takes in water, breaks it down into $H+$, $\ce{O2} $, and a spare electron.  The hydrogen ions are sent inside the thylakoid space, creating a concentration gradient between the stroma and the thylakoid space.  Since the ions cannot cross the thylakoid membrane, they must have a transport channel of some sort.  This channel is known as an ATP synthase, and ATP is synthesized from ADP and a phosphate group using the energy created by the hydrogen ion moving down the concentration gradient.  You are then left with an O2 group in the stroma, and an electron in the ETC.

PS-I takes that electron and basically just boosts its energy to produce NADPH using the H+ ion sent out of the thylakoid space during ATP synthesis.

In other words, PS-I cannot take place without the H+ and the electron from PS-II.  However, if PS-II were to run alone, it would simply mean that somewhere along the way either the oxygen would bind back to the H+ and electron to form water, or else the electron and H+ would be used elsewhere in the cell.  Thus it would be *PS-II* running in cyclic mode producing ATP.

Comment: But I think u swapped b/w ps I and ps II. As I'm sure it is ps I which runs in cyclic mode.